# JSF + Quartz scheduler with sleep function

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, quartz-scheduler

i need to create a scheuler with job1  conditions

1) when some condition fail in job1 i need to sleep the job for some time ?

queries

1) how can i do this in jsf with quartz 2.1.x or above

```
  public class SchedulerJob implements Job {

 int  i= 1 ;
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
       Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println("scheduler wotking with JSF and Hibernate "+ dateFormat.format(date));


        i=i+1;
        System.out.println(i);
           if (i==2)
           {
                System.out.println(i);
       try {

           // 15*60 =900 sec = 15 min

                Thread.sleep( 900L * 1000L); 
                 System.out.println("After 65 sec");
                  System.out.println("");
                // executing...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


}
    }

  }
```

quartz scheduler is this

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>AJob</name>
        <group>AGroup</group>
        <description>Print a welcome message</description>
        <job-class>com.mdis.scheduler.SchedulerJob</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>dummyTriggerName</name>
            <job-name>AJob</job-name>
            <job-group>AGroup</job-group>
            <!-- It will run every 5 seconds -->
            <cron-expression>0/5 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

this sleep is working ... but is this the proper way .

```
  Thread.sleep( 900L * 1000L);
```

Comment: There is many details missing, also you should provide some sort of starting point, what you have done so far

Comment: I don't think that sleeping is a good idea - this way you're blocking one thread from your job thread pool (assuming you have a thread pool). I think a better approach would be to run the job more often, check the condition and if it's not fullfiled, then just end the current execution and wait for the next one.